CsvHelper breaking changes - CsvSerializer
I am upgrading CsvHelper from a very old version (v15). I have this code:
      using (var csv = new CsvWriter(new CsvSerializer(output, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)))
      csv.WriteRecords(report);

However, it looks like CsvSerializer was removed at some point. How do I fix this?

Start reading the Change Log and Migration Steps from 15 to whatever version you've installed...

If all you are trying to do is write out records using CsvWriter, you should get all the help you need on the Getting Started page for writing a csv file. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#writing-a-csv-file.

However, it looks like CsvSerializer was removed at some point. How do I fix this?: Is this a trick question? If it doesn't exist, remove it just like any other invalid code/method/syntax.
